# Displaying dynamic content in Meteor using Dynamic Templates

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I've read through the (somewhat sparse) documentation on Dynamic Templates but am still having trouble displaying dynamic content on a user dashboard based on a particular field.

My Meteor.users collection includes a status field and I want to return different content based on this status.

So, for example , if the user has a status of ‘current’, they would see the 'currentUser' template.

I’ve been using a dynamic template helper (but have also considered using template helper arguments which may still be the way to go) but it isn’t showing a different template for users with different statuses.

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=userStatus}}
```

And the helper returns a string to align with the required template as required

```js
 userStatus: function () {
     if (Meteor.users.find({_id:Meteor.userId(), status: 'active'})){
         return 'isCurrent'
     }
     else if (Meteor.users.find({_id:Meteor.userId(), status: ‘isIdle'})) {
         return 'isIdle'

     } else {
         return ‘genericContent'

     }
}
```

There may be much better ways to go about this but it seems a pretty common use case.

The few examples I've seen use Sessions or a click event but I’d rather use the cursor if possible. Does this mean what I’m missing is the re-computation to make it properly reactive? Or something else incredibly obvious that I’ve overlooked.

Comment: Is the template not getting switched when the user's `status` value changes? Is it always showing the same template? If so which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [this approach discussed on the Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/dynamically-constructing-template-name/5945) which seems a bit cleaner.

```
  {{> Template.dynamic template=getTemplateName}}
```

And the helper then becomes:

```js
  getTemplateName: function() {
        return "statusTemplate" + Meteor.user().status;
    },
```

Which means you can then use template names based on the status:

```html
<template name="statusTemplateActive">
 Content for active users
</template>
```

(though keep in mind that Template helpers don't like hyphens and the data context needs to be set correctly)

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut for getting the current user object, [Meteor.user()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user).  I suggest you get this object and then check the value of the `status`.

```
userStatus: function () {
  if(Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.user().status === 'active') {
      return 'currentUserTemplate';  // this should be the template name
    } else if (Meteor.user().status === 'isIdle') {
      return 'idleUserTemplate';  // this should be the template name
    } 
  } else {
    return ‘notLoggedInTemplate';   // this should be the template name
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't pick up the different templates. Does it need a data argument?

Comment: @k_x That depends on the templates, the context they expect. Without it I would still expect it to render the template, but without the data that would come from the context. Check the browser console log,  are there any errors?